# How to extract data from the iphone backup on the PC

Tags: iphone, backup, data-transfer, whatsapp.app

I have a huge amount of image files on my Whatsapp, which are locally stored on the iPhone.

I do not see any way of moving these specific files from the iPhone to the PC, whereas of course from android this is as simple as connecting a USB cable between the two.

I have this iphone backup located in 
`C:\Users\%user%\Apple\MobileSync\Backup\%some code%\`
but the folder and file structure is seemingly encoded in a way only itunes/apple can decode.

Is there a way to extract an arbitrary file from the iphone?
Thank you.

Comment: What have you tried so far, what kind of research have you done already (including running a search in this site here)?

Comment: I tried searching google, apple's support and stackexchange. Most end up pointing me to fishy websites which ask you to download and run an executable which can supposedly do this. None (google, apple, stackexchange) showed any solution I can implement by myself without an external software.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I´m not a pro-windows user here, but I do use some good old USB connection from my Iphone and my work computer using Autoplay
[image]

So, if you did save your images locally into your device, you should be able to get them from there !

Otherwise you should change the parameters of Whatsapp to save your image into your Photos and then try Autoplay.

As you said, it **is** as simple as connecting a USB cable between the two.

Comment: Not sure this scales if, as the OP wrote, there are " a huge amount of image files on my Whatsapp" which aren't stored in the local photo library yet.

Comment: But he also claims ''which are locally stored on the iPhone''